# Changing a user name in heroku rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to edit a supplier name in my heroku database. I'm having trouble accessing the name attribute:

```
irb(main):015:0> Supplier.where(:name => "Test")
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Supplier id: 3070, name: "Test", email: "test@me.com", phone: "555555", website: "http://www.test.co.uk", region_id: 3, category_id: 8, created_at: "2015-02-20 13:28:59", updated_at: "2015-02-20 13:28:59", rating: 0.0, address: nil, facebook_url: nil, twitter_url: nil, google_url: nil, video_url: nil, slug: "test", logo_url: nil, image_one_url: nil, image_two_url: nil, image_three_url: nil, image_four_url: nil, description: nil, reviews_count: 0, source: nil, source_other: nil>]>
irb(main):016:0> _.name
=> "Supplier"
```

I'm not clear why _.name is resulting in "Supplier" rather than "Test".

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Supplier.where(:name => "Test")` returns multiple records.  Use

```
supplier = Supplier.where(:name => "Test").first
supplier.name
```

Comment: Thanks, that sorted it.